# cant populate utm parameter values on fluent form hidden fields

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am unable to populate values from a cookie into hidden fields in my form built with Fluent Forms (wordpress).

I have added the below code into my header to create and store cookies in the fields.

```
/ Function to set a cookie
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

// Save UTM parameters into cookies
var utm_source = getParameterByName('utm_source');
var utm_medium = getParameterByName('utm_medium');
var utm_campaign = getParameterByName('utm_campaign');
var utm_term = getParameterByName('utm_term');
var utm_content = getParameterByName('utm_content');
var lsource = getParameterByName('lsource');

if (utm_source) setCookie('utm_source', utm_source, 7);
if (utm_medium) setCookie('utm_medium', utm_medium, 7);
if (utm_campaign) setCookie('utm_campaign', utm_campaign, 7);
if (utm_term) setCookie('utm_term', utm_term, 7);
if (utm_content) setCookie('utm_content', utm_content, 7);
if (lsource) setCookie('lsource', lsource, 7);
</script>
```

In the form I have built using fluent forms, all these exist as hidden fields- utm_source, utm_medium, etc.

The default value for utm_source is {cookie.utm_source}

However, when I am testing - https://sttrinitynew.wpengine.com/property/arncliffe-apartments/?lsource=sbs&utm_source=google

I can see that the cookie is created with the right value, But the fields are still not populated with the utm values. In this case, utm_source remains empty.

I believe its something wrong with either my code or fluent forms itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue and this could be a plugin issue or a plugin conflict. In certain sites, the cookie value works well but in others in doesn't. Note that in the website where it works, you don't really need the JS script.